# Irreducibilty of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

$p$ is prime number and $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the $\mathbb{Z}/p$ field.

The polynomial given is $x^2+1$, and I don't understand how you can conclude that when $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, then $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you known the famous theorem that a prime is a sum of two squares if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$?

Comment: @HanulJeon An odd prime. $p=2$ is not equivalent to $1$ mod $4$ and $2=1^2+1^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that the unit group $(\mathbb{F}_p)^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$.  If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $4 \mid p-1$, hence $(\mathbb{F}_p)^\times$ has an element $i$ of order $4$.  Then $i^4 = 1$, so $i^2 = -1$ since the order of $i$ is not $2$.  Then $x^2 + 1 = (x-i)(x+i)$ is reducible.

(In the remaining case $p=2$, we have $x^2+1 = (x+1)^2$ by the [Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream#Prime_characteristic).)

Comment: @learnmore I've added a link to the Wikipedia page on the Freshman's Dream.  Of course, it's easily seen in this one case: $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 = x^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to help you, where this solution in number theory.

$x^2+1\equiv0 \pmod p  \iff x^2\equiv-1\pmod p \iff (\frac{-1}{p})=1 \iff p\equiv 1\pmod 4 $

$x^2+1\not\equiv 0 \pmod p  \iff x^2≢-1\pmod p \iff (\frac{-1}{p})=-1\iff p\equiv 3\pmod 4 $

where $(\frac{-1}{p})$ is Legendre symbol.